# Finding all submatrixes of a given matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

I've got a 2D vector which holds a matrix of integers, which looks like this:

```
    vector<vector<int>> Members;
```

What I am trying to find is a way on how to extract every possible sub matrix of a NxN matrix.

For example if I had a 2x2 matrix:

```
    0 -2
    9  2
```

It would output:

```
    0

   -2

    9

    2

    0
    9

   -2
    2

    0 -2
    9  2
```

Comment: What is 2D vector? Is it `std::vector` of `N*N` size?

Comment: Guess you're output also consists of two row matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-Matrix depends on the left-up point and right-bottom point, so you can give all possible locations and print them one by one like this:

```
//data stored in mat[max][max]
int max=5;//size of matrix
int i,j,m,n;

for(i=0;i<=max-1;i++)
    for(j=0;j<=max-1;j++)
        for(m=i;m<=max-1;m++)
            for(n=j;n<=max-1;j++)
                print(i,j,m,n);//a simple function
```